# shiny Element: Blank Spaces in inputId

Tags: r, shiny

I have multiple dinamically generated elements in my shiny application that have blank spaces in their inputId. The reason is that these inputId come from variables names from a tibble.

It is possible extract the values from these elements but is not possible to update them.

1 - Let's say i have a checkbox with: inputId = "first variable".

2 - It's possible to extract its value with: input[["first variable"]]

3 - but it's not possible updateCheckBox(session, inputId = "first variable", value = 1).

When I remove the blank spaces, it turns possible. Is there some solution to update an element with blank spaces on its inputId? Or is there any other solution?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

        #This is the element that has blank space in its inputId
        checkboxInput(inputId = "first variable", label = "Habilitar"),

        #This is the button that triggers the updateCheckBoxInput
         actionButton(inputId = "acao", label = "Acionar")
      ),


      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("impressao")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #get value
  output$impressao <- renderPrint({ input[["first variable"]]})

  #update
  observeEvent(input$acao, {

    updateCheckboxInput(session, "first variable", value = 1)

  }) 

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to just do `gsub(" ","_",x)` when creating the inputs. That way you always keep a nice one to one mapping between the original name and it's name in your `Shiny` application - if needed you can always do `gsub("_"," ",y)` on the result. So when `x` is a value obtained from the tibble:

```
x = "first variable"

 library(shiny)
 ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       #This is the element that has blank space in its inputId
       checkboxInput(inputId =  gsub(" ","_",x), label = "Habilitar"),
       #This is the button that triggers the updateCheckBoxInput
       actionButton(inputId = "acao", label = "Acionar")
     ),
     mainPanel(
       verbatimTextOutput("impressao")
     )
   )
 )


 server <- function(input, output, session) {
   #get value
   output$impressao <- renderPrint({ input[[gsub(" ","_",x)]]})
   #update
   observeEvent(input$acao, {
     updateCheckboxInput(session,  gsub(" ","_",x) , value = 1)
   }) 
 }

 # Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I had thought this solution too (using **`** ), although i have a long code and if i do this i will need to makes lot of changes in the code. So i was thinking if there is no other way to update the elements.
(But i consider make all this changes if ther is no other way)